# Synaptics touchpad synclient TapButton2 option

Tags: touchpad, configuration, synaptics, 14.04

I have a problem with my touchpad configuration. I would like to change the two-finger behaviour to middle button click, instead of right button. So I type in the console:

```
synclient TapButton2=2
```

And since then, when I tap with two fingers nothing happens. So to test it, I changed the TapButton2's value to 1 and it started to work as a left click, like it should. Only the configuration with the middle button does not work, do you have any solution?

Below is my synclient's configuration:

```
LeftEdge                = 1769
RightEdge               = 5423
TopEdge                 = 1644
BottomEdge              = 4544
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 238
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 108
HorizScrollDelta        = 108
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.03688
UpDownScrolling         = 0
LeftRightScrolling      = 1
UpDownScrollRepeat      = 1
LeftRightScrollRepeat   = 1
ScrollButtonRepeat      = 100
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 2
TapButton3              = 3
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 27
VertHysteresis          = 27
ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of how to manually set up a Synaptics touchpad. However, I have a couple tips that may work for you: 1) Unless it's explicitly disabled, left+right click works as a middle click in X. Perhaps you can configure two-finger tap as left+right click? 2) [EDIT: It's clearly not a clickpad, nevermind]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Due to fact that it is not the first problem with my touchpad I previously changed the button-map to avoid the issue with left physical button that acted like left and middle button simultaneously, so I typed:

```
xinput set-button-map "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

So in fact i couldn't use the middle button in TapButton2 option. So I decided to replace ExtBt7 with middle button using the command:

```
xinput set-button-map "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2 12
```

and after that I set the TapButton2 to new value.

```
synclient TapButton2=11
```

And voila! Everything works like it should. Tap with one finger is raported as a left click, with two fingers as a middle click.